# Save input into text file Metroapp

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, microsoft-metro

I have two text box in my metro app form..

I want that to be saved to a inf or a text file and I also want to read it from file again.

So can someone kindly help me the code for this issue pls....

I am trying to open this form only the first time whn i launch the application and I want another form to be open after that.. So wht I hve planned is I take this input and save it to a file and after that i will check if there r any value in the file and if its yes i show another form in the GUI..

If there are any suggestion they r warmly welcome..

Comment: So what is the issue ? Just implement your logic to code.

Comment: It's not necessary to write stuff to a file to store the result of a dialog for subsequent reading to control program flow.  Just plonk it in a _variable_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to save it to a file, you should use [`FileIO.WriteTextAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/hh701508.aspx) :

```
StorageFolder folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
StorageFile file = await folder.CreateFileAsync("data.txt", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

if (file != null)
{
    await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file, txtBox.Text);
}
```

To read it later, [`FileIO.ReadTextAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh701487.aspx):

```
StorageFolder folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
StorageFile file = await folder.GetFileAsync("data.txt");

if (file != null)
{
    string input = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);
}
```

Comment: You can but only to `ApplicationData.Current.RoamingFolder` or `ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder`, in Windows 8 apps you can't save files anywhere